# How to make simple Fresnel in blender Open Shading Language?

Tags: osl

I'm beginner in osl I want to make simple fresnel by Open Shading Language:

my problem is I can't find view direction in osl documention

```
shader Fresnel
(
    output color Out = 0.0,
)
{   
    vector Fresnel = 1.-dot(N,ViewDir);
    Out = Fresnel;  
}
```

and this is my error

```
Line 11: error: 'ViewDir' was not declared in this scope
```

I want result like this:

[image]

I tried to transform but not work:

```
vector WorldPos = transform("camera","world",point(0,0,0));
vector CameraWorldPos = transform ("camera", "world",(1.,0.,0.));
vector viewDirection = CameraWorldPos - WorldPos;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OSL global variable you're looking for is `I`

From the docs:

> `vector I`
>
> The incident ray direction, pointing from the viewing position to the
>   shading position P.

So, what's called 'View Dir' in your illustration is `-I`

Note that the 'viewing position' is the origin of *any* ray, not just those originating at the viewpoint/camera

EDIT: however, this is the shader which works as you expected in your post:

```
shader naive_fresnel(

           normal Normal = N,    
    output  float  Fac = 0.0 

)
{
    Fac = 1.0 - dot(normalize(Normal),I);
}
```

... which means `I` must be pointing *towards* the viewpoint? (BTW, the dot-product produces a scalar value, not a vector)

Loosely speaking, to Cycles, being physically-based, everything is a light, either directly, by emission, or indirectly, by scattering or reflection.

In standard use, how rays are actually cast is down to the [integrator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/integrator.html#integrator), not the shaders. OSL provides no direct access to the direction to lamps: the notion is that this kind of 'fake' is not required, or desirable, in a physically-based renderer.

Comment: oh thanks! I didn't test `-I`.I have another simple question that I will appreciate if you answer me what is LightDirection?  because I tried `Lambert = dot(N,I)` and it was black

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali see edit ..

Comment: thanks I asked [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130815/what-is-light-direction-equivalent-in-open-shading-language) before your editing I use 3dsmax osl do you know 3dsmax has access to light? can I access by something like this `point L = transform("Lamp");`

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali   I suspect not, in a path-tracer, for the reasons given in the edit, (although there are tricks, keeping manual track of the directions to objects in the scene, outside OSL). Let's see if a real expert comes along to give you another angle in their answer to your other question.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali .. the point being, that Phong and Blinn are methods for faking an approximation of the response of a surface to  direct lighting, whereas a renderer like Cycles _simulates_ it, by chucking thousands of rays around.

Comment: I need fake way just for practicing